# Capture the new value assigned to a variable

Tags: javascript

If I declare a variable as below, can I capture the new value assigned to the variable in JavaScript in any way?

```
var a = 1;
a = 2; // capture the value into a function of a hook during change
```

I tried this

```
'use strict';

var s = "test"; 
Object.assign(s, { set value(v) { console.log(v); } }); 
s = "tester";
```

The above code is working in the node shell when a new value is assigned but not in a `.js` file.

Even this did not work.

```
var events = require('events');
var em = new events.EventEmitter();
em.on('FirstEvent', function (data) {
    console.log('First subscriber: ' + data);
});

var s = "test"; 
Object.assign(s, { set value(v) { 
    console.log("v", v); 
    em.emit('FirstEvent', 'This is my first Node.js event emitter example.');
} }); 
s = "tester";
```

I do not want to wrap the variable into a function closure or a different object setter getter observer or assigning the value into a different object observer pattern to get the value.

I want to stick to value capture of basic variable of basic types of javascript; like `var s = 10`, `var s = "testr"`, `var s = undefined`, `var s = null`, `var s = []`, `var s = new Set([1,2, 3])`.

Technically every variable is an object in JavaScript. Is there any way? Should I be able to put an observer for assignation of a value?

Comment: Can I ask why you feel you need to do this? Generally it's indicative of a poor design implementation, which could be improved using other patterns

Comment: Perhaps [proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) is what you could use for this? (Although I agree that it would help to roughly know _why_ you want to do it, as it may help us give better suggestions and answers.)

Comment: Use a getter and setter and monitor that

Comment: Every value is *not* an object in JavaScript, and certainly not every *variable*.

Comment: did not work. `var s = "test"; Object.defineProperty(s, "value", { set(v) { console.log("new value is ", v, this.value); } }); s = "tester"; `

Comment: did not work. `var s = "test"; Object.assign(s, { set value(v) { console.log(v); } }); s = "tester";` does not console out the value

Comment: @Pointy in this `var s = "test"` is `s` not an object, a string object with its own prototypes?

Comment: No, strings in JavaScript are *primitive* values, not objects.

Comment: this is working in the node command shell env but not inside a .js file. what is going wrong? `var s = "test"; Object.assign(s, { set value(v) { console.log(v); } }); s = "tester";`

Comment: Whare are *basic variables* for you? Does pushing an item to an array count as value change? Or do you only track reassignments?

Comment: @Behemoth for object and array yes, new properties or new items pushing is considered a value change. I have the age old `.observe` polyfill for objects and arrays. but for now in the question to be specific and scoped I am worried about capture of a re-assignation of the new value into a variable.

Comment: @Jeroen The proxy does not allow variable checks for values that are primitive and non-objects like `var s = 1`, `var s = "test"`, etc

Answer (score 1):

Probably the most straight forward way of doing this is to use [getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) and [setters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set). For example:

```js
var a = {
  _value: 1,
  get value() {
    return this._value;
  },
  set value(newValue) {
    this._value = newValue;
    console.log(newValue); // register value change here
  }
};

a.value = 2;
a.value = 3;
a.value = 4;
```

---

However, I would usually avoid this kind of logic. Try not to *monitor* things but maybe use events or something similar. The usage of such patterns makes your code unnecessarily complicated and unreadable.

Comment: Any way I can avoid this method? Just explained the question better. apologies. `I do not want to wrap the variable into a function closure or a different object setter getter observer or assigning the value into a different object observer pattern to get the value.`

Comment: @Gary for plain variables declared with `var`, `const`, or `let` (as opposed to object properties), the answer is no (in JavaScript). There is no facility that allows a variable to be aliased or watched.

Comment: I have updated the code with checks I have done. Can you check if a .assign can work in .js file. I am able to get .assign console out the new value in the nodejs shell